# What is the best way to cite multiple reviews?

Tags: citing

I have an article which was reviewed after its publication and received a Zbl number. The same was later reviewed second time in another language in a journal.

For the journal I have the possibility to cite it (have a bib file), but I do not have such for the Zbl review.

I have seen that some add a field in the bib file like Zbl="0..".

I would like to cite both of the reviews.

Should I make one citation for the original article and add the Zbl field there, and a second citation for the journal's review?

Or should I add more fields to the original article, for both of the reviews? Is there some accepted way to cite multiple reviews?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you @Mensch do you know the answer of my question?